# Show number of selected childs in Extjs TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to show in node title the number of selected child items in ExtJS TreePanel.

When panel is rendered and treestore is loaded it looks like:

```
+ List 1
+ List 2
```

When Expanded

```
- List 1
--[ ] Item 1
--[ ] Item 2
- List 2
--[ ] Item 1
--[ ] Item 2
```

I'm trying to change main leafs text to this... (if it has selected items)

```
- List 1 (1 of 2 selected)
--[x] Item 1
--[ ] Item 2
- List 2 (2 of 2 selected)
--[x] Item 1
--[x] Item 2
```

I have no idea how to count correctly selected items and how to edit Text parameter correctly to save a possibility show default text value which it looked on tree render.

Sorry for my english and thank you!

Comment: Can you please add a simple fiddle?

Comment: @Andrew were you able to achieve this?